# IPv4 is leaking when using an IPv6 proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, ipv6, ipv4

We've purchased access to a set of proxies which all have different public IPv6 addresses. When we access sites such as whatismyip.com, however, it shows that we also have a public IPv4 address. I've looked up these IPv4 addresses (such as 172.69.162.56) and they belong to Cloudflare. I was told that most likely we are "leaking CDN", but I don't understand what that means and I'm no longer in contact with the person who said it. There are only a few of these IPv4 addresses shared among the hundreds of IPv6 proxies, and I'm afraid they are being used to tie our proxies together. There has been evidence suggesting as much.

So I suppose my questions are:

1) Please explain what he means by leaking CDN or what is likely to be going on here.

2) Is there a way to block those IPv4 addresses from being exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very normal part of using any kind of proxy (a CDN such as Fastly, Cloudflare, etc or something like squid on a corporate network). They generally add honest headers to say "Hey, I'm a proxy, the real user is on this IP address here". That's because the clients IP address is often a part of identifying session data for websites.

Cloudflare allow you to turn this off. [See this here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206776727-What-is-True-Client-IP-) (assuming that is the product you're using, I'm not actually entirely sure what you've purchased).